# Select multiple filters, display only markers that have common features

Tags: javascript, leaflet, filtering, leaflet.markercluster

I have a leaflet map, already working. Currently, I have multiple checkbox filters (almost 40 in total on two maps) : a user can select several markers at the same time. The filters represent "specialities", and when I click on a filter ,it show me the hospitals that have that speciality. So on the map, I can have clusters that show a hospital with several specialities, and individual markers that show differents hospitals with one speciality.

- If a user clicks on the filter A, it display for example 5 markers with feature A.
- If a user clicks on the filter B, it displays 5 markers with feature B.
- And when a user clicks on filters A & B together, it displays A + B, so the 10 markers, with individual markers, and clustered markers.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Each individual chekcbox must show corresponding markers, BUT as soon as I check several checkboxes at the same time, I want to display only the markers (hospital) where I can find the corresponding features. For example, if I click on filter A and B together, I would like to see only the hospitals where there are speciality A and B and hide marker with only one feature.

As I already coded all my functions, I want to avoid rebuilding new GeoJSON features. I tried but it duplicate the markers.

I'm looking for a loop like this (of course this is not working):

```
$('#filters input').on('click', function(){// if click on checkbox
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");//I can get the checkbox IDs here, which correspond to the feature name

if ($('#filters input:checked').length >=2 ){ // as soon as there are more than one checkbox checked    
    var checkboxes = $("#filters input:checked");
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {//for all checked checkboxes
            if(feature[i].geometry.coordinates == feature[i].geometry.coordinates){//if the markers have same coordinates
                return layer.feature.properties.Examen; // show me those markers
            }else{
                return false;// hide other markers
            }        
     }
}
})
```

I think I arleady have all needed information with the following code, but I don't know how to merge this to get what I need...

Here is a sample of one feature :

```
{
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "Examen": "iduronate",
                    "Prelevement": "DBS ou Buvard 1 tâche de sang (+ 1 contrôle) ou Sang total EDTA 5 ml (Leucocytes)",
                    "Envoi": "Envoi rapide à température ambiante",
                    "Laboratoire": "Secteur des Enzymopathies UM-BEP-DBTP-IBP",
                    "Chu": "CHU de Grenoble-Alpes",
                    "Adresse": "CS 10217",
                    "Cp": "38043 Grenoble Cedex 9",
                    "Professeur": "Dr Vergnaud Sabrina",
                    "Tel": "Tel : 04 76 76 54 83 ou 04 76 76 59 05",
                    "Fax": "Fax : 04 76 76 56 08",
                    "Mail": "svergnaud@chu-grenoble.fr",

                    "Url": "http://biologie.chu-grenoble.fr/",
                    "Mode": "Buvard"
                },
                "geometry": {

                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [5.7423258, 45.2015191]
                }
            }
```

To add that "iduronate" markers : I click on the checkbox with id "iduronate". If I uncheck the checkbox, it hides my markers.

```
$("#iduronate").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {

            iduronate.addTo(clusterade);
        } else {
            clusterade.removeLayer(iduronate);

        }
    });
```

Adding marker on the map, show the custom icon, and display the data

```
var iduronate = L.geoJson(examenData, {
        filter: function(feature, layer) {
            return feature.properties.Examen == "iduronate";
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature2,
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.marker(latlng, {
                icon: iduronateIcon
            })
        }
    })
```

And finaly an example of my filter

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" class="gaucher" id="iduronate" name="EnzymeDef_mps1[]">
   <label for="iduronate">Iduronate sulfatase </label>
<div>
```

I'm sorry I tried to post my code here, but it's too long for the "body"..So I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/yuyazz/pen/MWaoeOP) to show it in live.
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: If filter A is e.g. `feature.properties.Examen == "nacetylglucosaminidase"` and filter B is e.g. `feature.properties.Examen == "heparane_sulfamidase"`, and any given point feature has one and only one value for the `Examen` property (since that property is a string and not an array, etc), then no feature can meet both conditions at once, and therefore your question makes no sense.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to hide Markers which do not form a Cluster with Markers of the other property value? This sounds lile a strange UX, since clusters depend on zoom level, therefore you might hide everything at high zoom, whereas not hide anything at low zoom...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. A you can see on the codepen (when openned in full screen) each filter groups several markers.They can have different features or same features. Markers are hospitals, so at the same coordinates, one hospital can have many features A and many features B at the same time. What I realise is that when a hospital have several features, they are clustured. So I just need to show clusters when clicking on many filters and hide individual filters. I think the map itself is more telling than my explanations. Thank you. In fact, yes it totaly makes sens !

Comment: I recognize that it is not clear because I shorten my js file. For example feature.properties.Examen == "nacetylglucosaminidase"  have many occurence with some different informations, and so on for all my features. In fact the "properties" 
"nacetylglucosaminidase" acts like a category. Hope it's more clear..sorry if it wasn't :)

Comment: If two (or more) features have the *exact* same coordinates but different properties (as the case seems to be), my approach would be to merge such features beforehand (loop through them, index by coordinates, add properties to an array). Then you can filter *features* instead of *cluster visualizations of features* in (what seems to me like) a more sensible way.

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan, I think, given my low level in js, that I will opt for a jquery / css solution and expose my solution here, even if it is clear that your recommendations seem to me to be the way to go !

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. @Ivan, I tried in my GeoJSON file to create new features, but it duplicates my markers. And as I have more than 40 filters and near 100 features, the combination are huge. So I'm really looking for a loop or something more dynamic and I hope it's possible. I edited my question to make it more clear.. I'm really stuck.. If someone faced this issue...I take any solution !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume a simplified version of your dataset, e.g. a GeoJSON `FeatureCollection` containing points for clinics/departments in hospitals, where two (or more) clinics pertaining to the same hospital share the same position:

```
let clinics = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "clinic": "cardio", "phone": "11 22 33 44 55" },
      "geometry": {
         "type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.74, 45.20]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "clinic": "trauma", "phone": "66 77 88 99 00" },
      "geometry": {
         "type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.74, 45.20]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "clinic": "neuro", "phone": "77 66 55 44 33" },
      "geometry": {
         "type": "Point", "coordinates": [6.12, 43.88]
      }
    } 
  ]
};
```

My approach would be to manually loop through said GeoJSON `FeatureCollection`, indexing point features based on their coordinates, and aggregating their properties into an array, e.g.:

```
let clinicsByPosition = {};

for (let clinic of clinics.features) {
  // Let the index be the string representation of the coordinates array;
  // this is probably inefficient, but will suffice.
  // Note there are no sanity checks performed here (e.g. checking geometry type)
  let idx = clinic.geometry.coordinates.toString();

  // Does clinicsByPosition already have something in that index?
  if (clinicsByPosition[idx] === undefined) {
    // Create a new feature in that index
    // Initialize the properties of that new feature to an array with
    // one element, the properties of the clinic, and same geometry
    // than the clinic.
    clinicsByPosition[idx] = { 
      type: "Feature", 
      geometry: clinic.geometry, 
      properties: [clinic.properties]
    }
  } else {
    // Add the properties of the clinic to the already existing indexed
    // feature
    clinicsByPosition[idx].properties.push(clinic.properties);
  }
}

// Second pass: convert the "clinicsByPosition" data structure 
// into a GeoJSON FeatureCollection
let hospitals = {
  type:'FeatureCollection',
  features: []
}

for (let indexedClinicSet of Object.values(clinicsByPosition)) {
  hospitals.features.push(indexedClinicSet)
}
```

After that transformation, the aggregated data set would look like:

```
let hospitals = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: [
    {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [5.74, 45.2] },
      properties: [
        { clinic: "cardio", phone: "11 22 33 44 55" },
        { clinic: "trauma", phone: "66 77 88 99 00" },
      ],
    },
    {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [6.12, 43.88] },
      properties: [{ clinic: "neuro", phone: "77 66 55 44 33" }],
    },
  ],
};
```

Let's put that in Leaflet with some informative popups:

```
var hospitals = L.geoJson(hospitalsData,{
    onEachFeature: function(feat, marker) {
        // For this example, let the contents of the popup of a hospital marker
        // to be a concatenation of the data for all clinics in that hospital
        marker.bindPopup(feat.properties.map(function(clinicData){
            return clinicData.clinic + " - tlf " + clinicData.phone
        }).join("<br>"))
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

A [working example with that](https://plnkr.co/edit/iDGHKOWVO9sR2Zw5) looks not so bad:

[image: popup of an aggregated data point]

It should be clear now that there's just **one feature** per set of clinics on the same coordinates.

Filtering can be now done in a (IMHO) sensible way. Loop through the hospital markers in the `L.GeoJSON` instance, and loop through the properties of each related feature to see if the visibility condition for *any* of its components is met, e.g.:

```
function recalculateHospitalVisibility(){
    var cardioVisible = document.getElementById('cardio').checked;
    var traumaVisible = document.getElementById('trauma').checked;
    var neuroVisible = document.getElementById('neuro').checked;

    hospitals.eachLayer(function (marker) {
        // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some
        if (
            marker.feature.properties.some(function (clinic) {
                return (
                    (clinic.clinic === "cardio" && cardioVisible) ||
                    (clinic.clinic === "trauma" && traumaVisible) ||
                    (clinic.clinic === "neuro" && neuroVisible)
                );
            })
        ) {
            marker.addTo(map);
        } else {
            marker.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

[Working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/szeRkHuYge8NKrZu). Even if the code might look a bit convoluted, the example data is simplified (so my non-medical brain can work with it better), the use of iterators and data structures is a bit heavy, and optimizations are possible, it should get you on track.

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan. The level is so high for me that I need to read the code several times to understand !! But really thank you for taking the time, I'm going to try to adapt it to my map and see if it works ... I'm sure your example can be useful for many others !! thanks again

Comment: @blogob: make sure to _upvote_ the answer if you find it useful, and to _accept_ it if it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: @IvanSanchez, with the provided example, I unfortunately can't manage to use the awesome marker plugin (show different marker depending on feature value) neither I can't manage to show only markers that share same coordinates when clicking on multiple filters..The code is clearly cleaner and I learn a lot from it, but I'm stuck at the same point for lack of skills!  So I take the liberty of asking a similar question again to see if, from my code, I can find a simple loop to achieve my ends.

Comment: This in no way calls into question the usefulness of your example, quite the contrary. I will continue to work on it, but in parallel, I would like to get a result from my code to better understand how it works.